# Magento2 API call returns 404 when Entity Not Found but 200 if is found. Why?

Tags: magento2, api, status

Whilst designing a framework to synchronize objects (entity models) between Magento2 and our CRM, I have found that Magento's REST API will return a StatusCode of 404 with the following JSON

```
{No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue}
{[parameters, {
  "fieldName": "customerId",
  "fieldValue": 30
}]}
```

-when trying to GET a customer, but this happens with any non-searchcriteria required GET call.

IMO, 404 should be a route not found, an honest 404.  Entity not found should be a 204 (Content not found), or at the very least a 200 with the JSON that it returns.

Am I doing it wrong? Is it really supposed to return a 404 error, and I have to build my .net framework "improperly" to accomodate for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Magento team decided to use 404 erro code for not found entities.

You can find code here: `vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:45`